# How to retrieve query list of post_type in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin and need the list of post types existing in the WordPress backend, I checked the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) page of WordPress codex but could not find the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
<?php
// hook into init late, so everything is registered
// you can also use get_post_types where ever.  Any time after init is usually 
fine.
add_action( 'init', 'wpse34410_init', 0, 99 );
function wpse34410_init() 
{
$types = get_post_types( [], 'objects' );
foreach ( $types as $type ) {
    if ( isset( $type->rewrite->slug ) ) {
        // you'll probably want to do something else.
        echo $type->rewrite->slug;
    }
}
}
```

i think it will work for you